Dojo exportGrid as chunks
While the following code successfully exports the tabled data from the page to an Excel spreadsheet as a csv, it only does so up to around 9,000 rows- well below what Excel can accept. I've tried to break down the export into chunks of under 9,000 rows each, but haven't had success. Might there be some syntax to do this, such as a Dojo piece to a while statement?
on(dom.byId("exportGrid"), "click", function(){

        xxxGrid.layout.setColumnVisibility(4, true);
        dijit.byId("xxxGrid").exportGrid("csv", function(exportData) {...

Thanks,
Dave
